# How to add more labels on X axis (plotly, dynamic values)

Tags: r, plotly

I am using plotly to create graphs over time. I am looking for a way to add more labels on X axis (in my case I would like to see every second month under the X axis).
I am aware of *ticktext* and *tickvals* arguments although as far as I understand it they require very specific names of labels which does not work for me as the plot is a part of a dynamic application and values differ depending on user's input.
Is there a way to determine that I would like to see 11 X-axis labels no matter the values are?

```
Date <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 150, by = "week")
value = runif(150)
data <- data.frame(Date, value)

fig <- plot_ly(data, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~ Date, y = ~ value)

fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Theres an alternative way to solve this. You can build your graphic in `ggplot2` logic and then pass the graph object to `plotly` with `ggplotly` function. Its intereseting for peaple who understand ggplot better then plotly, like me.

You can manipulate x axis changing the `date_breaks` parameter inside the `scale_x_date` function

```
   fig_ggplot <- ggplot(data, 
                     aes(x = Date,
                         y = value))+
        geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1.5)+
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b %Y")+
        theme_minimal()

fig_ggplot

fig_plotly <- plotly::ggplotly(fig_ggplot)

fig_plotly
```

[image]